# Indexed View vs. Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, indexed-view

I had a long running query (relative to the data) that was hitting an indexed view. I thought an indexed view was physically stored data? I dumped everything into a table and ran the same query against the table and found that it executed almost 3x as fast. I was under the impression, which apparently was wrong, that an indexed view would act the same as a physical table in terms of performance. Just looking for an explanation.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you running under? Downlevel editions require the use of the `NOEXPAND` query hint in order to benefit most from the indexed view.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio version doesn't usually matter. run `select @@version` on your system and see if it matches what you posted, which would be sql server 2016

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4057118) - 13.0.4210.6 (X64)   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3

Comment: Tested out WITH (NOEXPAND) - nailed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What edition of SQL Server are you running under? Downlevel editions
>   require the use of the NOEXPAND query hint in order to benefit most
>   from the indexed view. – Damien_The_Unbeliever

This was the answer, thanks again